# Fields to be set in HTTP header

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-headers

I am calling a web service in iOS. For this, I need to set the header in `NSMutableURLRequest` object. My service takes two string parameters and returns data in JSON format.
What are the the fields that I need to set in the header (Both while using `GET` and `POST`) using the `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`.

We do not need to use `setHTTPBody:` while using `GET`.. right???

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question and I resolved (using some code from Iducool and Ankit Mehta) like this...

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];

//Specify method of request(Get or Post)
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

//Pass some default parameter(like content-type etc.)
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//Now pass your own parameter

[theRequest setValue:yourValue forHTTPHeaderField:theNameOfThePropertyValue];

NSURLResponse *theResponse = NULL;
NSError *theError = NULL;
NSData *theResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];

//Now you can create a NSDictionary with NSJSONSerialization
NSDictionary *dataDictionaryResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theResponseData options:0 error:&theError];
NSLog(@"url to send request= %@",theURL);     
NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionaryResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code which i am using to call a web service and thats working for me

```
+(NSString *)http_post_method_changed:(NSString *)url content:(NSString *)jsonContent{
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];
NSData *requestData = [jsonContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: requestData];
NSURLResponse *theResponse = NULL;
NSError *theError = NULL;
NSData *theResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];
NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:theResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"url to send request= %@",url);
NSLog(@"response1111:-%@",data);
return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both while using GET and POST We do not need to use setHTTPBody?
**setHTTPBody only make sense when you are using POST request. GET don't need it.**

For Header parameters do something like below

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];

//Specify method of request(Get or Post)
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]; 

//Pass some default parameter(like content-type etc.)
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//Now pass your own parameter 

[theRequest setValue:yourObj forHTTPHeaderField:@"your parameter name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

setHTTPBody is used when HTTP method POST is being used.

```
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120.0];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Here the data is nothing but NSData of JSON data that need's to be sent.